# Generate random number java

Tags: jakarta-ee

Have class for generation random numbers:

```
public class RandomNumber {

    public static int getRandomNumber(int n) {
        return new Random().nextInt(n);
    }
}
```

Use it in my switch

```
public crt createNewCrt() {
        if (RandomNumber.getRandomNumber(4) == 1) {
            switch (RandomNumber.getRandomNumber(4)) {
            case 0:
                /../
            case 1:
                /../

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But generation numbers always the same. What the problem?

Comment: My guess is that the Random class is seeded by the millisecond time when you create a new instance. Since the code is likely calling `RandomNumber.getRandomNumber(4)` twice within the same millisecond, it will have the same seed, and therefore the same first `nextInt()` value. Perhaps try having a static `Random` object in the class to use in the function instead of declaring a new one every time the function is called.

Comment: specify the seed for Random. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)

Comment: What's the reason for calling it twice in a row? Are you going to have more things if the first random number *isn't* one?

Comment: How do you know that the numbers are always the same? did you print them? From what I see there is at least a 75% chance that the function will return null..

In any case you should consider initializing Random once and use the same sequence for multiple call to nextInt()

Comment: The reason for first random is generate 25% chance

Answer (score 3):

```
public class RandomNumber {
    private static Random r = new Random();
    public static int getRandomNumber(int n) {
        return r.nextInt(n);
    }
}
```

Change your random generation to this. If you instantiate the Random class twice very quickly, it will use the same seed and generate the same numbers. If you hold the object in a static field, then you keep getting the next numbers from the same seed, instead of the first one over and over.

Comment: Thnx! It works.
Change my random to Random(System.nanoTime);
All problem was in seed

Comment: @Sunstrike The suggestion above to create one Random() instance and keep using it is much better IMHO. You are much more likely to get a random sequence that way and it is more efficent

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement at the beginning of your switch. The switch is only called if the random number  == 1. You can get rid of the if statement.

Comment: The `if` statement is intentional. It introduces a probability that the switch's block will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you are using a separate method.  Why not do:

```
public crt createNewCrt() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(4);

    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 0:
            /../
        case 1:
            /../

        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a Seed for the Random like this

```
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Because random is always based on calculations, so `Random` never a real Random.